# Java if condition for empty validations

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to java and i want to do a condition check and return a message

PersonalDetails Request: It holds the value for all the below infos

getID();

getName();

getDesignation();

getHomeAddress();

getOfficeAddress();

getEmailID();

getMobile();

getHomePhone();

getOfficePhone();

i want to check all values for empty then return message.

Like **"Your ID,Name, Mobile cannot be empty"** if i pass empty values to ID, Name, Mobile

Below is the sample snippet which has to do the check for all PersonalDetails Request

```
public static String checkValue(PersonalDetails Request) {
    String str="Your ";
    if(request.getID().isEmpty())
    {
         str="ID,";
    }
    if(request.getName().isEmpty())
    {
     str="Name";
    }
if(request.getDesignation().isEmpty())
    {
     str="Designation";
    }
if(request.HomeAddress.isEmpty())
    {
     str="Address";
    }
   str+= "cannot be empty"

    return str;
}
```

Is this right or any other easy approach will address the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you pass the values as parameterized constructor arguments, there you can check the values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple suggestions for your code:

1. Use camel-case for variables, methods etc. in your code. For example parameter should be named as `PersonalDetails request` and not `PersonalDetails Request`. These are standard coding conventions. Also getter/setter should follow the rules, check `HomeAddress` which seems to miss it.
2. Use `StringBuilder` class as it performs better specially in case of appending while in a loop.
3. You need to check for `null` before performing any operation else you will be facing a `NullPointerException`. You can also read about `Optional` in Java 8.

The code can be improved like:

```
public static String checkValue(PersonalDetails request) {
        if(null == request ) {
            //Throw exception or log/return message as per your need.
        }

        int some_appropriate_size = 50; // You need to decide about some_appropriate_size so that it starts with enough capacity for the full content we are going to append.
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(some_appropriate_size);

        stringBuilder.append("Your ");
        if(null!= request.getID() && request.getID().isEmpty())
        {
            stringBuilder.append("ID,");
        }
        if(null!= request.getName() && request.getName().isEmpty())
        {
            stringBuilder.append("Name");
        }
        if(null!= request.getDesignation() &&request.getDesignation().isEmpty())
        {
            stringBuilder.append("Designation");
        }
        if(null!= request.getHomeAddress() && request.getHomeAddress().isEmpty())
        {
            stringBuilder.append("Address");
        }
        stringBuilder.append( "cannot be empty");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if this is a static method or instance method ? public static String checkValue(PersonalDetails request)

Comment: The method declaration itself specifies the method is static. If it were instance method it would have been declared like:`public String checkValue(PersonalDetails request)`

Comment: No. My question was this functionality can be in a static method or it has to be an instance method. i'm confused to make a decision. Please advise

Comment: The method works on an object of class `PersonalDetails` and may not have any usage for other classes, so making it `static` wont be useful. IMO you should make it an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

No if the string contains `null` then it will through a null pointer exception.

You first need to check it for null then for Empty.

[Can we rely on String.isEmpty for checking null condition on a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970008/can-we-rely-on-string-isempty-for-checking-null-condition-on-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is correct but you forget to concat string in each if. If don't concate it will not have existing value but new value only.

```
  public static String checkValue(PersonalDetails Request) {
String str="Your ";
if(request.getID().isEmpty())
{
     str= str + "ID,";
}
if(request.getName().isEmpty())
{
 str= str + "Name";
}
if(request.getDesignation().isEmpty())
{
 str= str + "Designation";
}
if(request.HomeAddress.isEmpty())
{
 str= str + "Address";
}
   str+= "cannot be empty"

return str;
}
```

My suggestion will be to use StringBuilder to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's better to check not only `isEmpty`. It's better to check `null`, `" "` or `"-"` as well.

Before you check isEmpty or `"-"` or `" "`, make sure to check `null` to avoid getting `NullPointerException`